# Accessing sqlite tables from CMD for eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cmd

DDMS views Database only in eclipse. I want to view  table contents from CMD.
i reached upto sqlite3 /data/data//databases/PhoneBook

The DESC  command is not acessible..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adb isn't a folder, it's a tool - located in

```
<sdk>/platform-tools
```

To connect to sqlite3 on your emulator, you must first start a shell

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
```

Then, connect to your database using the sqlite3 command

```
sqlite3 /data/data/<package_name>/databases/<database>
```

You can use .help at this point for further assistance

Hope this helps :)

Comment: ea got d database. But d DESC command is not working ... How can i describe tables ,, any Idea dude.

Comment: I think I'd need a little bit more information as to what you're trying to do...  'desc' in SQL is to sort by descending order, so I'm not sure if that's your goal or something else.

Comment: @Jay dude as far as i know desc is for describing tables in sql. Anywayz thnakz 4 ur suggestions. I found that .schema command is somewhat similar to desc.

Answer (score 0):

See the `.tables` command in the [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) help to get a list of tables in the database

And if you are looking for column info

```
pragma table_info(TABLE_NAME)
```

And of course to get the contents of the table

```
select * from TABLE_NAME
```

I couldn't really tell what part you are asking... so there's 3 common sqlite commands for getting information about your database/tables, assuming you've connected to the database as per @JayJ's answer.